How to embed a Winforms App (.exe) into Unity?
I am building a Winforms application, which is used to display Google Maps. I want to fully embed it into my Unity application.
I did it by suggestion by GPT (lmao =))
EmbedWinforms.cs (Script attached to an object in unity)
public class EmbedWinForms : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public string winFormsAppPath = "Path to my .exe Winforms App";

    private Process winFormsProcess;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        winFormsProcess = Process.Start(winFormsAppPath);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Start winforms");
        winFormsProcess.WaitForInputIdle(); // Wait for the application to be ready for input

        // Get the window handle of the WinForms application
        IntPtr winFormsHandle = winFormsProcess.MainWindowHandle;

        // Get the window handle of the Unity application
        IntPtr unityHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

        // Set the WinForms application window as a child of the Unity window
        SetParent(winFormsHandle, unityHandle);

        // Get the dimensions of the Unity window
        RECT unityRect;
        GetWindowRect(unityHandle, out unityRect);

        // Move and resize the WinForms application window to fit inside the Unity window
        MoveWindow(winFormsHandle, 0, 0, unityRect.Right - unityRect.Left, unityRect.Bottom - unityRect.Top, true);
        System.Console.WriteLine("End move");

    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        // Ensure the WinForms application is closed when Unity exits
        if (winFormsProcess != null && !winFormsProcess.HasExited)
        {
            winFormsProcess.CloseMainWindow();
            winFormsProcess.Close();
        }
    }
}

I also tried using TCP based on this repo
However, both ways create a separate Winforms window.

I expect that the Winform application will be completely in the Unity space (as shown).

Is there any way to help solve this problem? Thank you so much !

Googling "unity winforms" gives a few results, for example this one https://forum.unity.com/threads/winforms-in-unity.479281/
